# ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified

Tags: sql, database, sql-order-by, distinct

I have sql query in which i want return rows with distinct value order by particular column.
like say,i want disntict batchno from ordertable order by locationid.

i have tried google also but not able to find out solution

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

that what i got every time i tried.

when not using distinct i got output but with duplicate rows using this query

```
Select Batchno,LocationId from Ordertbl order by case when[LocationId] =3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, [LocationId]
```

if i use distinct it gives me error these are query i tried out.

```
Select distinct CAST(Batchno as Varchar(MAX)),LocationId from Ordertbl order by case when[LocationId] =3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,[LocationId]
```

or

```
Select distinct CAST(Batchno as Varchar(MAX)),LocationId from Ordertbl order by case when[LocationId] =3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,[LocationId],[Batchno]
```

so this is things i tried but no luck.please help me.

Comment: What is the datatype of `Batchno`? Why are you casting it to `Varchar(MAX)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DISTINCT` doesn't allow any expression in the `ORDER BY` that is not also in the `SELECT` list (even if, as in this case, the expression could only yield one specific value for each distinct row). You can use.

```
SELECT Batchno,
       LocationId
FROM   Ordertbl
GROUP  BY Batchno,
          LocationId
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN[LocationId] = 3 THEN 0
            ELSE 1
          END,
          [LocationId]
```