# ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified error

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to list a field a certain way but sort it differently. Here is the query. Any way around this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT tsgroup
FROM   master
ORDER  BY RIGHT(RTRIM(tsgroup), 3),
          LEFT(rtrim(tsgroup), 3)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY`  instead

```
SELECT tsgroup
FROM   master
GROUP  BY tsgroup
ORDER  BY RIGHT(RTRIM(tsgroup), 3),
          LEFT(RTRIM(tsgroup), 3)
```

Comment: +1. This works for more than one column. Just repeat all columns in the `GROUP BY` clause. If you have calculated columns, it gets complicated. Wrap the query without `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` inside `SELECT * FROM (` and `) X`, and you can group and order by all columns whether calculated or data.

Answer (score 0):

like a hack:

```
select grp from (
select distinct tsgroup as grp
from master 
)
order by RIGHT(RTRIM(grp), 3) , left(rtrim(grp), 3)
```